# Meteor.call and passing object to a rendered component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I am working with Meteor to grab data from the server and render it based on certain GET parameters. My URL is `/course/:subject/:number`; with React Router, I'm getting the parameters correctly and using a `Meteor.call` function to grab data from Meteor (which also works just fine. I get the data that I'm looking for.) Meteor returns an object that I would like to pass into a component that will be rendered by React.

However, `this.state.thisClass` is `null` when the `render` method is called. If I use `componentWillMount` instead of `componentDidMount`, `render` is called twice: Once with the course as null, which causes an error, and once without an error and with the proper course (though, since there was an error, the page is just a white screen.)

Am I misunderstanding how `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` function? Should I be doing something else?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import CourseCard from './CourseCard.jsx';

// Permalink component - Component to render a CourseCard after searching for it in the database
export default class Permalink extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        const number  = this.props.match.params.number;
        const subject = this.props.match.params.subject.toLowerCase();

        this.state = {
            number: number,
            subject: subject,
            thisClass: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        Meteor.call("getCourseByInfo", this.state.number, this.state.subject, (err, foundClass) => {
            if (!err && foundClass) {
                this.setState({
                    thisClass: foundClass
                });
            }
            else {
                // 404
            }
        });
    }

    render () {
        return <CourseCard course={ this.state.thisClass } />;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but there doesn't seem to be any instance of `selectedClass` in your render method, did you mean `thisClass`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you for catching that!

Comment: So tracing it back, can you log out what `foundClass` is? I think the issue lies between the callback and the setState call

Comment: Ok, looks like `componentDidMount` is not being called at all, because the component never mounted due to the item I'm expecting not being there. I should have caught that earlier. Changing it to `componentWillMount` causes `render` to happen twice; the first where `thisClass` is null, causing an error, and the second where `thisClass` is equal to what I'm looking for.

Comment: `{ classFull: "info 3300 data-driven web applications" classNum: "3300" classPrereq: [] classSems:["SP15", "SP16", "SP17", "SP18"] classSub: "info" classTitle: "Data-Driven Web Applications" crossList: ["hoppEJ2q5mrudGjCk", "RuNgrBJFWLEraAbmx"] _id: "jAWAf97jNRDsCamxv" }`

Comment: You can always add a conditional around it `if (this.state.thisClass) <CourseCard... />`?

Comment: That was a major step towards doing it; I just had to modify another component a little. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about not rendering CourseCard when this.state.thisClass is null or empty?

```
 render () {
    return (
  <div>
  {
     this.state.thisClass ? &&
         <CourseCard course={ this.state.thisClass } />
  }
  </div>
 );
}
```